# silverlight speech to text

Tags: .net, silverlight, text, voice

Does anybody knows if it's possible to record a voice and transcribe it to text in real time?

I want to do that with silverlight or if it's not possible with the standard .Net framework

thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

The solution consists of five steps:

1. Entering text into a textbox.
2. Calling a Web Service to process the text.
3. Using Microsoft’s Text to Speech API to convert the text to WAV.
4. Decoding the byte array with a WAV decoding class.
5. Playing back the WAV stream with Silverlight’s MediaElement.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dd901770.aspx

Comment: Thanks, 
but what I want to do is the exact oposite. I want to get the text from a recorded voice !

Comment: if you have the voice recorded as a WAV, then you should only need to do step 4 and 5.

Comment: The OP wants Speech to Text not Text to Speech